# Searching through encrypted files: Doable approach or hazardous?

Tags: encryption, password-encryption

I want to write a simple text editor that stores the entered text as an encrypted string in a file on disk. There should be a search feature where the user can search through all encrypted files for a list of words the user entered. For that purpose the text editor would save the passwords entered by the user into an encrypted file.

The search function would load the passwords from the password file and search through the user's files for some given text. It decrypts each file with one of the passwords from the password list. If the decrypted text in its header contains a specific keyword, the decryption is considered successful and the search function would continue with the next file searching through it.

The file with the entered passwords is of course also encrypted. The user needs to keep the password to decrypt the password list in mind.

I'm no security expert and no encryption expert, either. I have a feeling that the approach described is too naive. I would therefore like to ask the security experts what they think about this.

Comment: Such an approach could work ... or it could fail spectacularly. If your not expert enough then the latter is very likely to occur. Your best bet is to find something already implemented that has withstood peer review and the test of time. The closest thing I can think of is your operating system encrypted drive container, or something like VeraCrypt.

Comment: Thanks James. I guess I will only use that text editor for my personal use then and not distribute it. For personal use it is good enough. The encrypted file with the password list I can store on some remote machine or delete it anytime I think I want to if it is stored locally.